# CodeIgniter joined table With SUM

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables

```
products   sale_items
--------   ----------
id         id
code       product_id 
name       quantity 
price      ...
...
```

count the number of sales per product, all in one query. I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
public function getProductsListing()
    {       
       
        $this->db->select("products.id, products.code, products.name");
        $this->db->from('products');

        $this->db->join('sale_items','sum(COALESCE(quantity, 0)) as qte', false)
        ->where("registers_id = '{$this->session->register_id}' and  sale_items.product_id = products.id", null, false);  
    
         
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach (($query->result()) as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
                var_dump($data);
            }
            return $data;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use CI, but I think you need to pass `false` [as the second parameter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#select:%7E:text=accepts%20an%20optional%20second%20parameter) to `select()`, to stop CI attempting to escape the column names.

```php
$this->db->select('p.id, p.code, p.name, IFNULL(SUM(s.quantity), 0) AS totalQuantity', false)
    ->from('products as p')
    ->join('sale_items as s', 'p.id = s.product_id', 'left')
    ->where('registers_id', $this->session->register_id) 
    ->group_by('p.id');

$result = $this->db->get();
```

Notice I switched `SUM(COALESCE(quantity, 0))` to `IFNULL(SUM(s.quantity), 0)` so the `IFNULL()` runs on the aggregate instead of every row.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply join table like this in codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('products.id, products.code, products.name');
$this->db->from('products');
$this->db->join('sale_items', 'products.id= products.product_id ');
$this->db->where(array('registers_id '=>$this->session->register_id))
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: the product select work, join dont work ?

Comment: how to add sum(COALESCE(quantity, 0))  in join ?